# how to open UIPageViewController on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

Looks like duplicate right ??

but i dig the internet and i found nothing ..

please someone help me how to open UIPageViewController on button click

if we want to open uiviewcontroller we can use this

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController =     storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextView") as NextViewController
 self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

but what about UiPageViewController ??

how to achieve that ??

Comment: In my opinion that should work if NextViewController is a UIPageViewController, what is the error?

Comment: If there is an important piece of data that needs to be passed to populate the pageViewController, you will need: `let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController =     storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextView") as NextViewController
NextViewController.importantDataVariable = ImportantData
 self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)` 
Before you can open it without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a storyboard segue. Make sure that your initial VC is embedded in a NavigationController. Then create a segue from initial to your pageViewController and give it an ID.

[image: Segue to PVC]

Next, in your initial view controller code, instead of instantiate, do push.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "seguetoPVC", sender: self)
```

Put that in your button click and it will allow you to open your PageViewController on button click. Hope this helps.